# Kubernetes certificate always disappear after few hours

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am new to kubernetes. I created a certificate in kubernetes for my validation webhook.
After approving the certificate, and checking if it is still there after few hours, by running

```
kubectl -n mynamespace get csr
```

However, it shows no resources found in the namespace. But if the certificate is newly created 
and run the same command above it shows the certificate.

Is this an expected behavior? where does the certificate go?

Please help. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior for security reasons. You should download the certificate using below command and keep it safe.

```
kubectl get csr my-svc.my-namespace -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' \
    | base64 --decode > server.crt
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#download-the-certificate-and-use-it

Comment: I found out that I can still use my downloaded server.crt even the approved csr has disappeared. Thank you for confirming that it is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

csr is short for `Certificate Signing Requests`

It dismiss after validated.

If your want to check certificates:

```
kubectl get cert -A
```

`-A` for --all-namespaces

Comment: As of Kubernetes v1.26 this does not seem to work: `$ kubectl get cert -A` ... 
`error: the server doesn't have a resource type "cert"`